# How do I control whether a HTML5 details tag is open or not with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, html-tag-details

[The HTML details tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp) is a collapsible chunk of content. You declare a closed (collapsed) details tag by writing

```
<details>Some stuff</details>
```

And an open (expanded) one by writing

```
<details open>Some stuff</details>
```

How do we dynamically add and remove attributes from a tag (in this case specifically the `open` attribute) with Angular?

Comment: You would probably have to write your own directive to handle this.

Comment: You may be interesting in checking out the details of the `ngDisabled` and related directives: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngDisabled They were built to save the same kinds of problems, and you could likely base your directive off the code for those

Answer (score 1):

Given that the `<details>` tag is not supported in many browsers you might want to consider using something else instead.  [This link](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-details-jquery) shows how you can create an equivalent to the `<details>` tag which will work in all major browsers.

But otherwise, as @Tim Withers states, you should look to build a directive that will allow you to change this.  Specifics depend on exactly how and when you are expecting to add/remove the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [ngOpen](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOpen) like so:

```
<details ng-open="boolean">
```